# i want to run this code while loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I assign the values automatically when the page load without having to invoke the hover or click any event actions. The colors will be changed based on user inputs or random color that will be generated automatically hover the container "someclass" will be the same for all.

```
<div class="container1">
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff13 " </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container2">
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffff15 " </div>
 </div>

 <div class="somecontainer">
 <div class="someclass"> " #ffgf19 " </div>
 </div>

 <div class="thecontainer">
 <div class="someclass"> " #0fff1a " </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container1">
 <div class="someclass"> " #cfff17 " </div>
 </div>

 <div class="mastercontainer10">
 <div class="someclass"> " #1fff13 " </div>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".someclass").hover(
      function() {
          var color = /#[0-9\A-F]+/.exec($(this).html())[0];
          $(this).css('background', color)
      }, function() {
          $(this).css('background', color)
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: try document.onload instead of $(document).ready

Comment: @the-naga-tanker have you got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this

```js
(function () {
        
        $(".someclass").each(function () {
         
                var html = $(this).html();
                var color = html;
                $(this).css('background', color);

        });
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">#ffff13</div>
    <div class="someclass">#ffff25</div>
    <div class="someclass">#ffff36</div>
    <div class="someclass">#ffff48</div>
    <div class="someclass">#ffff50</div>
    <div class="someclass">#87CEEB</div>
```

## Or

you Lookig for this

```js
(function () {
        var color;
       
        $(".someclass").hover(function () {
            var html = $(this).html();
            color = html;
            this.style.backgroundColor = color
        });
        $(".someclass").mouseleave(function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "white"
        });
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:white;" class="someclass">#ffff13</div>
    <div style="background-color:white;"  class="someclass">#ffff25</div>
    <div  style="background-color:white;" class="someclass">#ffff36</div>
    <div  style="background-color:white;" class="someclass">#ffff48</div>
    <div  style="background-color:white;" class="someclass">#ffff50</div>
    <div style="background-color:white;"  class="someclass">#87CEEB</div>
```

Comment: @TheNagaTanker  please accept and vote the answer if you got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the hover function in an anonymous function

## JavaScript

```
(function() {
  // insert code here

})(); // anonymous function
```